# Vertigo Vs Dizziness

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Please imagine someone is feeling dizzy. Would it be possible for them to say:

> - I have vertigo.

I googled the Google Ngram [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20feel%20dizzy%2C%20I%20have%20vertigo&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20dizzy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20vertigo%3B%2Cc0) and found out that one may say the sentence "I have vertigo," but very rarely. This is why I doubted if it is used in common English these days or it is considered as something scientific or very technical.

Comment: *vertigo* is a symptom of a medical condition, with various causes. It occurs when normal balance mechanisms don't work right. *dizziness* is more broadly used, and can refer to any sensation of unsteadiness, due to many causes including fear and oxygen deprivation. It also has other unrelated meanings, which may upset your Ngram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> vertigo

is a subset of

> dizziness

If you have "vertigo" then you are dizzy, but there are many things which may make you dizzy.

> My dizziness is due to lack of food. *(hypoglycemia)*
>   My dizziness is due to the altitude. *(oxygen deprivation)*

Comment: Peter, what I understand from the previous post is that "vertigo" is usually caused by looking down from a very high place. Do you confirm it or I'm somehow mistaken?

Comment: [Vertigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertigo) is the sensation that things are spinning around, [acrophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrophobia), "the fear of heights" is often [confused with vertigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrophobia#Confusion_with_vertigo) the dizziness associated with "vertigo' can happen from any number of reasons, the confusion probably comes because of the Hitchcock movie starring Kim Novak and Jimmy Stewart in the lead roles.

Answer (score 4):

**Vertigo** is specifically the feeling of spinning or whirling when you are not actually moving, and is very often caused by looking down from a very high place.

**Dizziness** is a broader term, used to describe a variety of symptoms including vertigo, for example, unsteadiness (a sense of imbalance or staggering when standing or walking), lightheadedness or feeling as if you are about to faint. Dizziness, or being dizzy, is arguably more of a layman's term.

In the context you have provided, *vertigo* is a noun, and you have used it correctly.

> I **have** vertigo.

However, it is not common to use '*dizziness*' in the same way, i.e. '*I have dizziness*'. It's much more common to use the adjective 'dizzy', e.g.

> I **am** dizzy
>
> I **feel** dizzy.